# Pq da esse erro: "return makes pointer from integer without a cast "

Tags: ponteiro

```
int *aloca_vetor(int MAX){
int i,*vetor;
for ( i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
    vetor[i] = (int*) calloc (1, sizeof(int));
}
return (vetor);
```

Erro:

```
projeto.c:13:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     vetor = (int*) calloc (1, sizeof(int));
```

Não sei o que ta causando esse erro.

Comment: João, tenho umas dúvidas: Está fazendo um teste, onde quer alocar um espaço de memória não sequencial para cada item desse vetor? Ou está querendo apenas alocar um vetor com o tamanho de `MAX`? Além disso, tem alguma razão também para não usar o `malloc`?

Answer (score 4):

Vamos acertar primeiro a nomenclatura. Não está dando erro, é um "warning", aviso de inconformidade que, normalmente, o compilador pode passar, mas pode causar problemas... no seu caso não irá causar. Pelo menos não por causa do *warning*.

Explicando o *warning*:

Você criou um ponteiro para int (`int i, * vetor;`). Quando você acessa um ponteiro com o indicando o indexador, ele "resolve" o ponteiro para o tipo dele, portanto, você está tentando colocar um tipo `int*` dentro de uma variável `int`.

Por que eu disse que isso não causará problema?

- Porque `int` tem o mesmo tamanho na memória de `int*`

Pelo que entendi ali do seu código, você está tentando fazer uma rotina que retorna um ponteiro para o vetor alocado de tipo int com tamanho X... sua rotina tem uma série de problemas conceituais :(.

Você deveria fazer algo desse tipo:

```
int* aloca_vetor(int tamanho) {
  return (int*)malloc( tamanho * sizeof(int) );
}
```

E depois dar um `free` no ponteiro retornado quando não for mais utilizar.